# Panning between two active audio signals

Tags: circuit-design, mixer, preamp

I want to have a circuit that pans between both my active pickups.

I have designed a simple summing opamp with a 50k center click potentiometer acting as a panner but even though it worked, when at the center position there was a considerable volume drop.

I tried with a 10k potentiometer and that did the trick but unfortunetly the potentiometer needs to be 50k as I can't find any other that is smaller in value, center click and has a bush long enough to go onboard on a bass guitar. All resistors used on that circuit were 10k.

I found this schematic that I am attaching and I was wandering, if I use the 50k potentiomter as a panner in R3, what kind of adjustment to the resistors should I make in order to get a smooth blend without losing too much volume at the center position?

I have also tried a summing opamp configuration with two volume pots coming from the preamps but at center position the volume was considerably louder than with each pickup by itself.

[image]

Comment: You may need to better define the "panning." This may require either the use of some "standard" that already exists (I'm not an expert on this, so I can't direct you) or else you may need to experiment to find out what works for you. I'd look to what others have done, myself. It may be too reliant upon human vagaries to just solve with blind math, I think.

Comment: Try with the pot wiper to the op-amp virtual earth (Vin-) and get rid of the two 10 k resistors to the right of the pot. Or just try without getting rid of them. Personally I always use the pup closest to the fret board and have a tone control I can vary. I never use a bridge pup. (Gibson E335 not original).

Comment: Thank you Andy. My pickups are both going to two separate preamps that I have made. They are exactly the same at their ouput, same buffer design. So, I'm actually mixing two active signals. I meant to ask, what differene would it make connecting the wiper to Vref instead of ground?

Answer (score 2):

I recently reverse-engineered a powered speaker that used this circuit to mix between "dry" (no effects) and "wet" (effects, reverb, etc.) versions of a signal. Keeping a constant volume throughout the range of this control is fairly important.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvctGS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

They used values for R1 and R2 that are 1/5 the value of the pot. R4 and R5 are equal to the value of the pot, and the ratio of R6 to R4 and R5 sets the overall gain.

Comment: Thank you Dave. That seems to be very helpful. What I am a bit concerned about is that by increasing the value of R4 and R5 it might actually change the high end of the audio. I tried with a similar circuit and the input mixing resistor was 47k and that was sucking the tone out of the original sound. But anyway, will give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

When panning between uncorrelated signals, you want to attenuate the signals by 3dB in the center position.  That would be what you do for two pickups on different guitars.  But your signals will be highly correlated, so you need to attenuate by 6dB in the center position in order to have a smooth balance (essentially tieing both inputs together should make the balance pot stop having any effect).  I think you more or less get there by having the resistors next to the 50k pot be 50k as well.  The feedback resistor will have to be larger to make up for the attenuation of the resistor network but, uh, I am fuzzy on the details.

But the key design criterion (when! inputs are closely related like they are for your application) should be that tieing the inputs together should stop the position of the balance pot from having any effect on the output.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to experiment to find the best panning curve for your application (and preference).  Start by changing R3 to the 50k pot that you want to use.  Increase the gain of the circuit by increasing the value of the feedback resistor (the extreme right-hand resistor) from 10k to 47k.  Adjust that value to suit your prreferences.

If you leave the input resistors (the two left-hand resistors) at 10k, the panning pot will not have as much effect at the center range of travel as at the ends.  If you want the pan action to be more smooth across the range of travel, increase the value of the input resistors and increase the value of the gain-set resistor to compensate for the added attenuation.

Be sure to use a decent-quality low-noise op-amp.  A LM358 is far too noisy for this application.

[Edit]

Andy brings up a very valid point: the wiper of the pot can't go to ground unless you are using a bi-polar supply for the op-amp.  Either connect the pot wiper to the reference supply (and add a large-value bypass capacitor to ground) **OR** just put a large value capacitor in series with the wiper to ground.

Comment: Thank Dwayne. I am using an op2171. When you say to increase the value of the gain-set resistor, do you mean the feedback resistor, or would that be the 10k resistors right hand from the potentiometer on the input?

Comment: The gain-set resistor is the feedback resistor (extreme right-hand side of your schematic)

Comment: So, if I connect the Wiper to Vref, would I also need to add a capacitor to ground? If that's the case, wouldn't it be easier to just connect to ground with a large capacitor(assuming something like 10uf) in series?